# typo3 ke_search Results per Page

Tags: search, typo3

I am trying to get ke_search to work. It works, it searches, but I am trying to make links which shows results per page. In the extension in the typo3 backend there is a possibility to insert the results per page. I tried to insert in my search input field:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="tx_kesearch_pi1[resultPage]" value="100" />
```

But this field is ignored. My Idea was to insert Links which change the value 100 to 50 or 10, so that the list ist shorter or longer.

Answer (score 1):

ke_search is using the FlexForm value, which is saved in the database and isn't a GP parameter.

If you want to do it quick, try to modifiy the ke_search extension by overriding this value:

ke_search/lib/class.tx_kesearch_db.php

```
public function getLimit(){
$limit = $this->conf['resultsPerPage'] ? $this->conf['resultsPerPage'] : 10;
```

and replace it with

```
public function getLimit(){
    $fVal = t3lib_div::_GP('tx_kesearch_pi1');
    if($fVal['resultsPerPage']){
        $limit = $fVal['resultsPerPage'] ? $fVal['resultsPerPage'] : 10;
    } else {
        $limit = $this->conf['resultsPerPage'] ? $this->conf['resultsPerPage'] : 10;
    }
```

To add this to your pagebrowse you have to modify this value:

ke_search/lib/class.tx_kesearch_lib

```
public function renderPagebrowser() {
$resultsPerPage = $this->conf['resultsPerPage'];
```

and replace it with the same get param

```
$resultsPerPage = ($fVal['resultsPerPage'] ? $fVal['resultsPerPage'] : $this->conf['resultsPerPage']);
```

Or you can create a clean hook.